# How to write a count like this in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
SELECT COUNT(id), age FROM `red_cross_volunteers` GROUP BY age;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `Sequelize.fn` in `attributes` option and `group` option while calling `findAll`:

```js
const stats = await RedCrossVolunteers.findAll({
  attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('id')), 'age_count'], 'age'],
  group: ['age']
})
```